# Sql Server Inner Join with Like clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
with temp as(select top 5 * from tblJobs) -- **select data from tblJobs**
select a.FirstName,a.LastName,a.Email ,b.City,a.Latitude,a.Longtitude 
from tbljobSeeker as a --select data from tblJobSeeker

inner join tblCity as b on( b.CityID = a.CityID) -- **inner join for CityName **
inner join temp as d on d.Latitude like CONCAT('%',a.Latitude,'%' ) 
and d.Longtitude like CONCAT('%',a.Longtitude,'%') 
-- ** inner join for top 5 jobs with basis of Latitude & Longtitude **
where CAST(a.Latitude AS DECIMAL(9,2))  BETWEEN CAST(d.Latitude AS  DECIMAL(9,2))-0.10 AND CAST(d.Latitude AS DECIMAL(9,2))+0.10

and CAST(a.Longtitude AS DECIMAL(9,2)) BETWEEN CAST(d.Longtitude AS DECIMAL(9,2))-0.10 AND CAST(d.Longtitude AS DECIMAL(9,2))+0.10
and a.IsDelete = 0
```

I have a job table in which 13 jobs and I have another table jobseeker. **I want result of email column from job seekers**.Both table common parameter is ***Latitude & Longtitude*** in **varchar** but i got empty set something is wrong in query

tblJobSeeker data

```
ID  JobSeekerCode FirstName LastName Email          Latitude             Longutude
1   JS0001        Someone   Example abc@xyz.com   22.494636249263564 88.37204933166504  
2   JS0002        Someone1  Example1 abc1@xyz.com 19.11986822166177  73.0070686340332   
3   JS0003        Someone2  Example2 abc2@xyz.com 19.20447041013782  72.8207581040624

TABLE tbljobs 
ID  JOBCODE EmployerCode     Latitude           Longutude
1   JOB0001 EMP0018         19.08580444766317   72.8364372253418    
2   JOB0002 EMP0008         28.7041             77.30435371398926       
3   JOB0003 EMP0022         19.162519142081003  72.83819675445557   
7   JOB0006 EMP0001         19.06917553583066   72.83819675445557       
8   JOB0007 EMP0001         19.130248167229208  72.84673690795898
```

Comment: At a guess your latitude, longitude joins and filters are filtering everything out. Your first step is to confirm whether records are returned if you exclude the joins on `temp`. Also try removing the `where` on a. The only way you will solve this is by removing parts and isolating which one is causing you issues. There's no way anyone can post a viable solution without some kind of sample

Comment: If `d.Latitude = 51` and `a.Latitude = '51.001'` then these are not going to match. There are many reasons they wouldn't match but we're just guessing because we don't know what the data looks like.

Comment: actually, he takes perfect match but I want similar match like d.Latitude = 19.34 and a.Latitude = '72.25'

Comment: In what way are those similar? What data type is the latitude and longitude column? If you want assistance please post sample data and explain how they should match.

Comment: latitude and longitude column in ** varchar(max)**

Comment: None of the latitudes or longitudes match. You need to describe how you want them to match. i.e. less than 5 degrees difference? Unless you describe this no one can help.

Comment: suppose in tblJobs  Latitude  = 19.08580444766317 I want only 19.08 and result between 19.08 + 00.10 and 19.08-00.10 similarly for  Longitude serch

Comment: Please edit the question and add this information. Since you are storing it in `VARCHAR(MAX)`, you first need to convert it to something like `DECIMAL(19,17)`. But I'm guessing you have rubbish in there so you won't be able to do it on the fly. So first you need to run this and see if it gets to the end without errors: `SELECT CAST(Latitude AS DECIMAL(19,17)) As Lat, CAST(Longtitude AS DECIMAL(19,17)) As Lng FROM tblJobs`. Note you spelt Longitude wrong, but I've kept the spelling.